# Python refactoring

Tags: python, refactoring

I have a following piece of code that I would like to refactor. Basically there are three functions which are copy-pasted except for their names X, Y, Z. Only the function names `create?` and the string in the variable `errContext` changes.

```
class Derived(Base):
    def createX(self):
        try:
            errContext  = "X has fatal errors."
            # .... code .....
        except Exception, e:
            raise w

    def createY(self):
        try:
            errContext  = "Y has fatal errors."
            # .... code .....
        except Exception, e:
            raise w

    def createZ(self):
        try:
            errContext  = "Z has fatal errors."
            # .... code .....
        except Exception, e:
            raise w
```

My first shot at refactoring it is as follows:

```
class Derived(Base):
    def _create(self, name):
        try:
            errContext  = "%s has fatal errors." % (name)
            # .... code .....
        except Exception, e:
            raise w

    def createX(self):
        self._create('X')

    def createY(self):
        self._create('Y')

    def createZ(self):
        self._create('Z')
```

Is this correct? Or is there any better way to do this like using closures? Also if there are pointers to tools which would help me refactor Python/C++/Tcl code it would be helpful. 
Right now I use [Clone Digger](http://clonedigger.sourceforge.net/) and [CPD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.1.2/cpd.html) for the copy paste detection. They are very useful.

Comment: What are `X`, `Y` and `Z`?  How do they differ?

Comment: @RobertHarvey This is from the legacy code I have. X, Y, Z are just strings. All the three functions are 20 line Python code which differ only in `errContext` variable

Comment: So add a string parameter to your function, and pass `X` `Y` or `Z` into the new parameter.  Do whatever you want with the parameter inside the function.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, may be he want's to preserve backwards compatibility but still want's the luxury to make code functionality changes only in one place?

Answer (score 0):

Looks good to me if you want to preserve backwards compatibility. Otherwise just keep one create function in your new class as you have it.